# Effective Java Item42, at least one input argument

Tags: java

Effective java 2, Item 42 propose an elegant way for a method take at least one argument, and fail at compile time if the input is empty. The code is shown below in the `min()` method, however I am wondering what is the elegant way to call this method, because now simply passing `list` will trigger an compiler error.

```
public class OneOrMoreArgs {
    public static int min(int firstArg, int... remaining){
        // but then how do you call the function with a int[] ?
        int _min = firstArg;
        for(int x: remaining){
            if(_min < x ){
                _min = x;
            }

        }
        return _min;

    }
    public static int sum(int... list){
        int s = 0;
        for(int a: list){
            s += a;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5};

        System.out.println(OneOrMoreArgs.sum(list));
        System.out.println(OneOrMoreArgs.min(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, you can't just pass in an `int[]` anymore.  The answer is "you can't."

Comment: The compile error you are getting is because the method signature; you have to pass an `int` as a first parameters, then 1..n `int`s. The method signature and [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) are things completely different.

Comment: Is the purpose of this new signature to force the user of the method to do the checking?

Comment: Imagine if you *could* pass an `int[]`... then you could pass `new int[0]`, defeating the point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the elegant way to call it would be to do

```
OneOrMoreArgs.min(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

If you need to pass in an array, you could add an additional method signature like this:

```
public static int min(int[] args){
    if (args == null || args.length < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("... some error message...");
    }

    return min(args[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length));
}
```

It needs to be noted that:

1. This solution is inefficient as it requires the array to be copied.
2. The check is executed at runtime instead of compile time, so you lose the benefits of the solution proposed by Item 42.

It looks like for your use case, you're better off just declaring a method that takes an array parameter, like the `sum()` in your example.